# Is it possible to install arcore on project without relying on google play services for ar

Tags: android, arcore

Is it possible to install entire arcore libraries on android project without have to rely on "google play services for ar" before user can use the arcore features?

I tried the augmented faces sample and it works fine but users have to install "google play services for ar" app before they can use the feature.